# Find order of $f(x)$ when $g(f(x))\to\infty$ as $x\to \infty$

Tags: analysis, limits, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

> Assume $f(x)$ is a function of $x$. How $f(x)$ should be (orderwise, with respect to $x$) in order to make the following term tend to infinity as $x\to\infty$?
>   $$g(x)=\sqrt{f(x)} \large \exp\left(a x\left(1-\frac{b}{b+\ln(1+c/f(x))}\right)\right)$$

where  $a,b,c>0$.
In other words, what are the necessary and sufficient conditions on $f(x)$ such that the above term tends to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$?

**My solution:**

If $f(x)=o(1)$. then, I can probably say that $g(x)=\sqrt{f(x)} \large \exp\left(a x\right)$ (I am not sure if this step is 100% true, I know I should use taylor expansions, etc to make sure it is right). Since $g(x)=\omega(1), {f(x)}=\omega(\exp(-2a x))$. Therefore, one set of solution is $f(x)=o(1)$ and $f(x)=\omega(\exp(-2a x))$.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: That question is not about ordered sets, lattices or the like.  It is a analysis problem.

Comment: As far as I know the order regarding infinity is expressed by $O(\ldots)$ while $o(\ldots)$ consideres the limit towards zero.

Maybe you should try to eliminate the exponential factor in some way in order to find some useful hints.

Comment: @Keinstein you are misinformed, asymptotic statements like  $f=O(g)$ must be accompanied by which limit is taken (although context makes it clear sometimes), and the above means $|f|\le C|g|$ eventually for some constant $C>0$, and $f=o(g)$ as $x\to\infty$ means $f/g→ 0$.